# Prove the set of polynomials whose constant coefficient is zero is an ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, proof-verification

My concern for my proof is I am running off some big assumptions that seem already true. If someone could show me a better way of explaining parts 1 and 2, that would be awesome.

Also, our professor has allowed "super-closed" to deal with closed under inverses.

My attempt

Assume $A$ is a ring.

Let $J$ consist of all elements in $A[x]$ whose constant coefficient (CC) = $0$

$\textbf{(1)}$ Let $a,b \in J$. Observe $a \oplus b$ is a polynomial whose CC is $0$

$\textbf{(2)}$ Let $c \in A[x], a \in J$. Observe $c \otimes a$ is a polynomial whose CC is $0$

Since $J$ is closed under $\oplus$ and super-closed under $\otimes$, $J$ is an ideal. $\blacksquare$

Comment: It might be good to show via a computation what the constant term would be.  For example, the element $a$ could be written as $a=a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots+a_1x+0$.  If you work similarly for $b$ and $c$, you can show the results explicitly.

Comment: Technically, you should show that $(J,+)$ is a subgroup of $A[x]$, so you need to show that $0$ and inverses are in the set.  This is straight-forward.  Also, you could also check $a\otimes c$ unless $A$ is commutative.  Finally, I'm not really sure what you mean by "super-closed" and why it matters on $\otimes$.

Comment: @MichaelBurr Super-closed is the term we use to show that J is an ideal rather than just a sub-group. $\forall c \in A, b \in J$, if $c *b \in J$, then J is super closed and he said there is a theorem that if you are super closed, you get inverses.

Comment: Does that "super-closed" theorem require that the ring is a ring with unity?

Comment: Sorry, you are right, the theorem requires the ring to be a ring without unity since if J is an ideal with unity, J = A. So, for this problem, I believe we are assuming that our ring is a ring without unity (the book goes off and on when they use unity)

Comment: I was talking about full ring $R$, not the subset $J$.  The reason that you need an identity is if $a\in J$, then you'd like to use $(-1)a=-a\in J$, but you only have such an element to multiply by if $R$ has a unit.  Regardless, you can use the results that you've already proved in class.  The original comments hold in that you shouldn't just claim the result is ok, but actually compute what the constant term would be under each operation.

Comment: In this example, wouldn't super closed work since $(0+x+x^2+...+x^n) * -a =$ inverse of $0+ax+ax^2+...+ax^n$? And for all other polynomials we could just adjust the coefficients? The reason I am bringing this up is basically your idea to use super-closed would imply J=A for all ideals implying we could never have proper ideals.

Comment: Super-closed does not imply that $J=A$ (I'm not assuming that $J$ has the unity).  Super-closed should work in this example (provided $A$ has a unit).  You still need to actually do the computations for (1) and (2) instead of just stating that the result holds.